# decrypt .asc file from enigmail not work

Tags: pgp, enigmail

I'm new on `PGP` and I'm trying to see how It works:

I can encrypt and decrypt files with my keys pair, but If I download an .asc file from thunderbird with enigmail I don't be able to decrypt it. I explain better

I send to my self an email with my (only) public key. Via thunderbird all works, it decrypt automatically the message. There is an .asc attach, too and If I download it and I type 
`gpg file_name.asc` nothing happen.
[image]

Why? where I wrong?

**EDIT**

I made a mistake!
The attached file on my email is the public key. I checked the box to do it

Comment: It will write the result to an output file or write a error message. 'Nothing' is not an expected result. It is probably a good idea to specify the file name you expect with `--output`

Comment: with --output I get nothing again. I edit my message with a snapshot  of my terminal

Comment: But, Could that attach be the public key? Not the message?

Comment: Ok that Screenshot shows not 'nothing' it shows a key listing. So yes your Asc file is the key. This also explains the file name.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't thought it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You show the output of a key file. Also the name looks like a key ID. So you did not save the encrypted body but a key attachment.